# How to create custom label in 'options_from_collection_for_select' method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

I would like to modify what the user sees in a drop down given a collection. Instead of just the "product" field being visible, I would like it to be something like "Vender Product, version" or something like that.

**Can this be done with the 'options_from_collection_for_select' method?**

I have a Ruby on Rails view with this line in it (slim):

```
select.form-control#external_tool_question_external_tool name="external_tool_question[external_tool]"    
    = options_from_collection_for_select(@external_tools, :id, "product")
```

Controller:

```
@external_tools = ExternalTool.all
```

Model (through a few different migrations):

```
t.string :value
t.string :validator
t.string :example_answer
t.boolean :required, :null => false, :default => true
t.boolean :is_file_upload, :null => false, :default => false

add_reference :external_tool_questions, :external_tool, index: true
```

What I've tried:

- I looked at this documentation, but could not find what I was looking for: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-option_groups_from_collection_for_select
- I tried just guessing, but this did not work:

code:

```
options_from_collection_for_select(@external_tools, "id", "product vendor")
```

(also... I can't figure out how to get the select tag to work... I'm using simple form as well... not really the pressing issue, but just a side issue)

Comment: I am not sure what I want is possible... I just saw that this method calls "value_for_collection" and that doesn't look like I can send multiple values in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alter your `ExternalTool` like following:

```
class ExternalTool
  def label
    "#{vendor} #{product} v #{version}"
  end
end
```

When you set the variable in your controller:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def form_action
    @external_tools = ExternalTool.all
  end
end
```

You can use it in your template as follow:

```
options_from_collection_for_select(@external_tools, "id", "label")
```

Take a note, that `options_from_collection_for_select` in his third argument accepts the name to be called. Here we're using `label` in `ExternalTool`.

Hope that helps! Good luck!

Comment: I ended up reworking things, but this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution, but it does change quite a bit. Instead of using the 'options_from_collection_for_select' method, use the 'options_for_select' method:

Controller

```
tools = ExternalTool.all.pluck(:id, :vendor, :product, :version)
@external_tools = []
tools.each do |et|
  @external_tools.push(["#{et[1]} #{et[2]}, v #{et[3]}", et[0] ])
end
```

View

```
select.form-control#external_tool_question_external_tool name="external_tool_question[external_tool]"
  = options_for_select(@external_tools)
```

I guess I could also create a method in the model that does this.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass Proc to **options_from_collection_for_select** as **text_method**.

e.g.

```
options_from_collection_for_select(@external_tools, "id", 
  proc{ |external_tool| external_tool.product + external_tool.vendor } )
```